# Can't find a certain node in XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

My problem is that I can't seem to get a list of nodes I need. I have tried multiple solutions and it doesn't seem to work. This is a part of my xml file:

```
<findItemsByCategoryResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
    <ack>Success</ack>
    <version>1.13.0</version>
    <timestamp>2016-08-23T07:33:22.497Z</timestamp>
    <searchResult count="100">
        <item>
            <itemId>152210133431</itemId>
            <title>...</title>
            <globalId>EBAY-GB</globalId>
            <primaryCategory>
                <categoryId>218</categoryId>
                <categoryName>Magic the Gathering</categoryName>
            </primaryCategory>
            <galleryURL>
http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/meIDrVqhmbpQMYCxzeUvR9Q/140.jpg
</galleryURL>
            <viewItemURL>
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/MTG-See-Unwritten-Khans-Tarkir-MYTHIC-MINT-/152210133431
</viewItemURL>
            <paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
            <autoPay>false</autoPay>
            <location>London,United Kingdom</location>
            <country>GB</country>
            <shippingInfo>
                <shippingServiceCost currencyId="GBP">1.1</shippingServiceCost>
                <shippingType>Flat</shippingType>
                <shipToLocations>GB</shipToLocations>
            </shippingInfo>
            <sellingStatus>
                <currentPrice currencyId="GBP">0.5</currentPrice>
                <convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="GBP">0.5</convertedCurrentPrice>
                <bidCount>0</bidCount>
                <sellingState>Active</sellingState>
                <timeLeft>P0DT0H19M12S</timeLeft>
            </sellingStatus>
            <listingInfo>
                <bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
                <buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
                <startTime>2016-08-18T07:52:34.000Z</startTime>
                <endTime>2016-08-23T07:52:34.000Z</endTime>
                <listingType>Auction</listingType>
                <gift>false</gift>
            </listingInfo>
            <condition>
                <conditionId>1000</conditionId>
                <conditionDisplayName>New</conditionDisplayName>
            </condition>
            <isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
            <topRatedListing>false</topRatedListing>
        </item>
    </searchResult>
    <paginationOutput>...</paginationOutput>
    <itemSearchURL>...</itemSearchURL>
</findItemsByCategoryResponse>
```

**Normally there are 100 item nodes in this xml file, I just shorted the file.** I tried to get the ''item'' nodes and everything inside in a XmlNodeList, but when I debug it says it contains 0 items. After this I want to retrieve some data, as you can see in the code. Note: I tried a lot of xpath values!
Here is the code I used:

```
            XmlDocument xmlText = new XmlDocument();
            xmlText.Load(basicUrl);
            XmlElement root = xmlText.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList xnList = root.SelectNodes("//item");
            foreach(XmlNode item in xnList)
            {
                string title = item["title"].InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine(title);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath Expressions are always namespace aware (if the Element has a Namespace then the XPath must reference it by namespace). Also, in XPath expressions, the 'default' namespace is always in the URI "". In your case you should do something like this :

```
        XmlDocument xmlText = new XmlDocument();
        xmlText.Load(yourXml);
        XmlElement root = xmlText.DocumentElement;
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlText.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("t", "http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services");
        XmlNodeList xnList = xmlText.SelectNodes("//t:item", nsmgr);
        foreach (XmlNode item in xnList)
        {
            string title = item["title"].InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(title);
        }
```

SelectNodes with namespace :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4bektfx9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How about explaining _why_ this would/could help?

Comment: Dont quite understand it and it doesnt seem to work, can you give me a little more information? Or maybe search it with linq instead of Xpath?

Comment: Xpath is a very good way to search in XML  I edited my answer (I tested the code with the xml provided in the question)

Comment: It seems to work! I got two more question how do I know I need to use this kind of code to read the nodes? and can I use this to read for example the "<currentPrice>" node. or what would be the difference?

Comment: Could you help with htis last thing pls?

Comment: Same way : `var p = item.SelectNodes("t://currentPrice", nsmgr);`

Comment: It is not working, this gave me a compile error, so I changed it to //t:currentPrice and I get all the currentPrices in the xml(since there are about 100 items). I just need the one in THIS item node. Can you help me with that?

Comment: it should be item.SelectNodes("/t:currentPrice", nsmgr)